# How to use onPress in component React Native Maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to change the coordinates of my MapView when I click on a Marker so that it centers the . This way it can show the Callout properly. I am trying to use animateToCoordinate, but nothing happens and the function doesn't even shows any logs.. What am I doing wrong?

In my component that contains the Marker I have the following:

```
class Place extends Component {
  fadeOut = () => {
    this._mapView.animateToCoordinate({
    latitude: 28.869236999,
    longitude: -81.234822999
   }, 2);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: this.props.latitude,
            longitude: this.props.longitude
          }}
         onPress={() => this.fadeOut()}
        >
          <View onPress={() => this.fadeOut()}
            style={styles.markerWrap}>
            <View><Text style={styles.markerTitle}>{this.props.title}</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.marker} />
          </View>
          <Callout
            tooltip={true}
            style={styles.box}
          >
          <View style={styles.boxShadow}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, fontWeight: "600", marginBottom: 10}}>
                {this.props.title}
              </Text>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, lineHeight: 18,}}>
                {this.props.description}
              </Text>
              <Button style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Se mer</Text>
              </Button>
          </View>
          </Callout>
        </Marker>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Place;
```

My app.js

```
<MapView
          style={styles.map}
          showUserLocation
          followUserLocation
          showsIndoors={false}
          showsTraffic={false}
          loadingEnabled={true}
          customMapStyle={MapStyle}
          region={this.getMapRegion()}
          provider="google"
          >
            <React.Fragment>
            <Place
              latitude={37.784362}
              longitude={-122.406872}
              title="Meny"
              description="Det er lett å lage gode kjøttfrie måltider. Her finner du både gode oppskrifter på vegetariske og veganske retter som passer til middag og lunsj, og hverdag og fest!"
            />
            <Place
              latitude={37.786562}
              longitude={-122.408872}
              title="Dwell"
              description="Det er lett å lage gode kjøttfrie måltider. Her finner du både gode oppskrifter på vegetariske og veganske retter som passer til middag og lunsj, og hverdag og fest!"
            />
            </React.Fragment>

      </MapView>
```

Currently it is not changing coordinates and shows like this:

[image]

Would also like to be able to use onDeselect to make the Callout animate.

Comment: I don't see you code setting `this._mapView` to mapView's ref

Comment: @skyboyer How can I do that?

Comment: I tried `fadeOut = () => { this.props.map.animateToCoordinate({ latitude: 28.869236999, longitude: -81.234822999 }, 2); }` and adding `ref={ map => { this.map = map }}`to <MapView>

Comment: I don't see this in code. without ref it definitely should not work. so update you code and let's see if there is something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding this to :

```
ref={ map => { this.map = map }}
```

And using it as a prop to the  component like this:

```
map={this.map}
```

So I can use it like this:

```
  fadeOut = () => {
    this.props.map.animateToCoordinate({
      latitude: this.props.latitude,
      longitude: this.props.longitude
    }, 5);
  }
```